# Sharepoint 2010 GlobalNavigationNodes

Tags: sharepoint-2010, navigation

Good day, I am looking for solution to make **custom top navigation menu**.

I got site collection and 3-4 nested sites. Builtin top navigation menu shows link like this:

**| SiteCollectionLink | NestedSite1 | NestedSite2 |** etc.

when i use:

> myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.RootWeb;
>       PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(myWeb);
>       SPNavigationNodeCollection nodeColl = publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalNavigationNodes;
>       foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodeColl)
>          {
>           //node processing
>          }

i got only NestedSite1 and NestedSite2 as nodes with no main node as it's not in there.

**So i wonder how can i take first node?**
 (builtin navigation menu sohws it as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself, if anyone futher will face it, try this:

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb
```